# Prometheus endpoint is a blank page - using kamon with Prometheus reporter in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, kamon

As the title says, I'm trying to collect system metrics using kamon and expose them to Prometheus.

On http://localhost:9095/,  I can briefly see the below message:

```
# The kamon-prometheus module didn't receive any data just yet.
```

but after refreshing several times I get a blank page. The kamon status page at http://localhost:5266/#/ shows 38 metrics.

Am I missing something?

My setup is as follows, in my main method, at the very top I have

```
Kamon.init();
```

I have added this in my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
            <artifactId>kamon-bundle_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
            <artifactId>kamon-prometheus_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I assume you also added the reporter `Kamon.addReporter(new PrometheusReporter())`. Does http://localhost:9095/metrics shows the same ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez I believe the reporter is activated by including the dependency in the pom. Yes, localhost:9095/metrics is also blank.

Comment: From the documentation of [Kamino](https://archive.kamon.io/documentation/1.x/reporters/kamino/) and of [kamon-prometheus](https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-prometheus/blob/master/README.md#adding-the-reporter-to-your-project), this seems to be required. I don't know this techno in particular, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

After a tip from the kamon gitter channel(thanks Diego Parra!), changing the dependency versions worked for me.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
            <artifactId>kamon-bundle_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kamon</groupId>
            <artifactId>kamon-prometheus_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key change to fixing this is updating `kamon-prometheus` to version `2.0.1`

As mentioned here: https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/issues/566